# CSS resize:both aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, resize, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to maintain aspect ratio 1:1 on `div` tag with CSS `resize` property. Is it possible to do so?

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/kFmY8/106/) has no aspect ratio. Any suggestions?

Comment: There are quite a few questions on stackoverflow about constraining [aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=constrain+aspect+ratio) -- do any of those help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it "resize:horizontal" and then resize the other way with javascript:

markup:

```
<div id="elementID" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#000;resize:horizontal;overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

​
js:

```
jQuery('#elementID').mousemove(
    function(e){
        var elem = jQuery(e.target);
        elem.height(elem.width());        
    }
)​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/valentinas/kFmY8/121/

The problem is that you need to check somehow when the element changes. AFAIK there is no event fired when the element is resized, so you would have to check in intervals to get reliable results. My example observes mousemove, but that is not reliable because you can actually move the mouse out of the element while resizing.

Comment: No. Only window object has onresize event, DOM elements don't have it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onresize